# How to use this using on trigger on created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to apply style on the clicked element of many with class name "wordratediv". How can I use `this` according to this structure  ?

```
$("#div4fullmovieresponse").on("click", "div.wordratediv", function(){
              $("div.wordratediv").css("background","black");
        });
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: $(this).css("background","black");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put `this` inside the brackets.

```
$("#div4fullmovieresponse").on("click", "div.wordratediv", function(){
          $(this).css("background","black");
    });
```